# Drive IR laser from ESP32

Tags: transistors, mosfet-driver, infrared, esp32

my goal is to send 38kHz signal on IR laser (5V) (have 3 laser that takes 60mA, 120mA and 400mA). PWM signal that generates 38kHz goes from ESP32, so 3.3V 40mA max.
I will do short shots max 1-2s with 30 minutes del.ay

on Q1 I try 2N2222 with R1 220ohm but I have problem with saturate them enough from ESP32.

So what transistor and restore I have to use to drive up to 400mA laser with 38kHz from 3.3 40mA ESP32, or I have to switch to N-MOSFET, if yes what Logic Level N-MOSFET can do 38kHz freq.

Thank you for any advise.

[image: Transistor]

Answer (score 2):

The 2N2222 is a fairly old low power transistor not really suited for this application.

Take a look at the [datasheet](https://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/2n2222-datasheet.pdf). The most relevant parameters in this case are:

- \${V_{BE}}_{sat}\$ (Base-emitter saturation voltage): max. 1.3V for a base current of 15mA, 2.6V for 50mA
- \${V_{CE}}_{sat}\$ (Collector-emitter saturation voltage): max. 1V for a collector current of 500mA
- \$h_{FE}\$ (DC current gain): min. 30 for a collector current of 500mA
- \$R_{th\space j-a}\$ (thermal resistance from junction to ambient): 350K/W

To drive 400mA of collector current with this transistor, you will need a base current of at least \$I_B = \frac{I_C}{h_{FE}} = \frac{400mA}{30} = 13.4mA\$

We will use the datasheet parameters for 500mA collector current (instead of 400mA), and 15mA base current (instead of 13.4mA), because these are quite close. If we had graphs in the datasheet, we could read the exact values from there.

Now, to calculate the base resistor for a base current of 15mA, we also need to take into account the base-emitter saturation voltage and the I/O voltage of the ESP32. Under 15mA load, the ESP32 GPIOs will probably not be able to keep the output at 3.3V, it might drop to 3.0V or even less. Check the ESP32 datasheet electrical characteristics to be sure.
\$R_B = \frac{V_{IOH} - {V_{BE}}_{sat}}{I_B} = \frac{3.0V - 1.3V}{15mA} = 113\Omega\$

This is the maximum resistor value to reach your desired collector current, for saturation you would use an even lower value (without exceeding your maximum base current rating). You could try \$100\Omega\$, or even \$82\Omega\$.

But now what about the power dissipation in the transistor? It is the sum of the collector and base losses combined: \$P_{tot} = ({V_{CE}}_{sat} * I_C) + ({V_{BE}}_{sat} * I_B) = (1V * 400mA) + (1.3V * 15mA) = 420mW\$

This is below the maximum allowed power dissipation of 500mW, but the transistor will quickly get hot without cooling: \$T_j = T_{amb} + (P_{tot} * R_{th\space j-a}) = 25°C + (420mW * 350K/W) = 172°C\$, which is below the surprisingly high maximum junction temperature of 200°C, but still very toasty. You might get away with it, if you only switch the laser on for a second or two.

The better solution, as you already suggested yourself, would be to use a logic level N-channel MOSFET. No problems with the ESP32 GPIOs having to source current, less power dissipation, less heat. The switching frequency is so low, it is not really a concern for the MOSFET selection in this case.

**TL;DR: Try 100 ohms or less for a 2N2222, or better just use a logic level MOSFET if available.**